# Are we able to call dictation feature on Mountain lion on button click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, wxwidgets

Mountain Lion dictation feature is invoked by default while pressing the fn key twice in a text control.

I would like to know if it is possible to invoke the same feature from other controls and events, for example invoke it after a button click event?

I would like my application to use the default dictation feature provided by Mountain lion. My cross platform application (wxWidgets) has an editor that is derived from wxControl, which does not have the default behaviour for invoking this dictation feature; the feature works works fine if I use a default text control instead.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
NSAppleScript *scriptForCMDKey = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Events\"\nset theProcess to first process whose frontmost is true\ntell theProcess\nrepeat 2 times\nkey down {command}\nkey up {command}\nend repeat\nend tell\nend tell"];
[scriptForCMDKey executeAndReturnError:nil];

NSAppleScript *scriptForFNKey = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Events\"\nset theProcess to first process whose frontmost is true\ntell theProcess\nrepeat 2 times\nkey code 63\nkey code 63\nend repeat\nend tell\nend tell"];
[scriptForFNKey executeAndReturnError:nil];
```